# Allow line breaks at hyphen characters ("-") in URL strings

Tags: macros, line-breaking, urls

**Problem:**

I have created a command that colors URL strings in a certain way. URLs, unlike text, do not break at hyphen characters in my document.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{{\color{editorBlue}\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\inlinecode{127.0.0.1:3000/html/chapter2/assignment1/articles-diary-fruits.html}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

URLs should line-break and continue on a new row where possible, for instance in the present case, after `articles-`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting. "Hyphenation" is generally described as the process of locating permissible line break points in words *and*, if necessary, inserting a hyphen character at the end of the first part of the word that's gotten broken into two parts. What you're looking to do isn't, technically speaking, hyphenation. Instead, it's granting permission to insert line breaks after any pre-existing hyphen characters that may be present in a URL string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(simplified the answer)

Load the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`.

```
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
```

and replace `\texttt` with `\url`.

Using `\url` rather than `\texttt` will also be useful if the string to be typeset contains characters -- such as `#`, `&`, `~`, and `_`, to name but a few -- that are "special" to TeX.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{{\color{editorBlue}\url{#1}}}
% use '\nolinkurl' instead of '\url' if 'hyperref' package is loaded as well

\begin{document}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block

\smallskip
\inlinecode{127.0.0.1:3000/html/chapter2/assignment1/articles-diary-fruits.html}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for completeness, here's a second solution, which doesn't use `\url` (or `\nolinkurl`) directives. Instead, it loads the `listings` package and employs the `lstinline` macro. Observe that the working assumption is that the `|` character (which is used as a delimiter) doesn't occur in the URL or code string. If this assumption is incorrect, just employ a more suitable delimiter character.

Here's an MWE (no screenshot, since the output is the same as above):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines,moredelim=[is][\ttfamily]{|}{|}}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{{\color{editorBlue}%
\lstinline{|#1|}}}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\smallskip

\inlinecode{127.0.0.1:3000/html/chapter2/assignment1/articles-diary-fruits.html}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that not all `\inlinecode` are url, they are sometimes plain text. Would the proposed solution still work?

Comment: It works, but it makes links of everything in the pdf file, which is not desired. Is there a way to get hypens only for `\texttt{ }`?

Comment: Solved. Added `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces}{url}` before `\documentclass` and then used `\nolinkurl`.

Comment: @kexxcream - Great. :-) Note that I rewrote and simplified the answer a bit, so that future readers wouldn't have to read through all the comments in order to make sense of what's going on.

Comment: @kexxcream - I've gone ahead and posted a second possible solution, which is based on the `\lstinline` macro of the `listings` package.